# Can I split Google analytics require/send into separate script tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

Can i do this?

Put this in the HEAD:

```
      <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

      </script>
```

And this, somewhere in the body on another part of the same page?

```
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce');

///transaction info

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Or does the ecommerce require/send both have to be in the one script in the HEAD.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to do this because following GA instructions, i need to put a function that converts transaction info from PHP to Javascript in the body of the page. And if i leave the e-commerce stuff in the head, it return function doesn't exist, because the function im calling to get the data in the GA code is below in the body.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the ecommerce code below the main tracking code (you can easily test it out by running the code in your console after the page has loaded, and checking if the transaction hit is sent). But just note that if your page doesn't completely load for some reason, and you have your ecommerce code at the bottom, then there may be a chance that that code doesn't get run, and you will lose the ecomm tracking.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have to do this because following GA instructions, i need to put a function that converts transaction info from PHP to Javascript in the body of the page. And if i leave the e-commerce stuff in the head, it return function doesn't exist, because the function im calling to get the data in the GA code is below in the body.